# Most effective way of exporting data to excel?

Tags: javascript, excel, export, uri

So most SO answers I've found for exporting data to excel involve using URIs with `data:`.  Is this the best client-side way of doing it (at least on Windows, it doesn't seem to work with Macs)?

Answer (score 1):

> So most SO answers I've found for exporting data to excel involve
>   using URIs with `data:`

Err...what do you mean and can you provide some links please?

That aside there are various ways you can do it - choose the one most appropriate. One way is what you mention (I can't understand it unless you post some links).

Another way: Arrange all your data as a multi-line csv string:

```
a, b, c, d
e, f, g, h, i
...
```

and send it to the server. The server 'service' just takes this string and returns a CSV representation which will be correctly downloadable. That is take the string paste in a file by the name 'myfile.csv' and return the file to the user.

Yet another way (hacky): Show a textarea with the CSV "in" it and ask the user to copy/paste it into Excel. CSVs are easily split into multiple columns on copy-paste.

If you are using Google Spreadsheets - then you could populate the text area with TSV (Tabbed Space Values) i.e. a tab `\t` separates two columns instead of a comma. A copy/paste into Google spreadsheets would be across columns

Use whatever approach suits you best. Know your goals (i.e. the why) before selecting an approach and the value/worth of that approach after selection.

Comment: You may want to accept the answer (or another one if someone posts) but a good thing to keep in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the client requirement of flash, you can use [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify).

Also, if PhD's answer was the one you used, you might want to give his answer the 'accepted' check :)